# User Only Has Access To One File

Tags: server, privileges

I'm working on an appliance that has a web based GUI for setting up the network on an Ubuntu headless system. Initially the system will be set up for DHCP but one of the initial configurations will be to apply a static IP address to it, using the GUI.

I'm sure it's going to happen that if they end up inadvertently submitting **incorrect** TCP/IP settings through the GUI, the appliance will either reboot or restart the networking services, but now the user has no access to the GUI via a browser.

I'm thinking of setting up an Ubuntu "Network Disaster" user whose credentials are known to the end user which would permit  them to log into the system, only via a terminal session (keyboard and monitor plugged into the appliance).

However, I only want them to have access to /etc/network/interfaces once they've logged in.  Ideally they're locked down to their home folder (or perhaps /etc/network is set to be their home folder) and can't navigate anywhere else on the file system.  The only file they have read/write access to is the interfaces file.

Is this possible?  I've read a lot of posts about setting up SSH users etc etc but I've not seen anything about restricting one user to just their home folder and that's it...?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if you want to keep them from viewing other files, so this may work for you.

Sudo allows you to define an entry in the sudoers file that will allow a specific non-privileged user to issue a specific command with with specific arguments at elevated privilege.

From the [sample suoders](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sample.sudoers)

```
# joe may su only to operator
joe     ALL = /usr/bin/su operator
```

It seems something like this would serve you;

```
joe     ALL = /bin/vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

or, even better

```
joe     ALL = /bin/vi /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg
```

Comment: Yes, I want to keep them from viewing ANYTHING else on the system, just having access to the interfaces file (and being able to read/write to it).

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a user to be able to see, have access to, and change a single file, vi is not really an option. The reason is that anyone using vi can immediately just drop to a shell within vi and run whatever commands they want, especially if they are within vi as root, which would most certainly be the case if they were editing `/etc/network/interfaces`. In fact, allowing them to log in and obtain a shell of any kind will immediately fail your objective.

Here is a two-part solution I propose that you try:

Summary:

1. Allow a user to sftp only a specific file to only a specific location without being able to obtain any other kind of shell.
2. Create and cron job that automatically checks for changes and conditionally copies a "new" interfaces file into place and restarts networking.

Guide:

1. Set up a user that can only use ssh protocol for sftp applications. The accepted answer in the following post worked great for me:

   https://serverfault.com/questions/354615/allow-sftp-but-disallow-ssh

   Notes:

   - For the sake of convenience, you can just used the sftponly name for your user as well, as the sftponly group will be automatically generated
   - Using `/home/sftponly` as the users' home directory is perfectly acceptable. This is what my user sftponly looks like in /etc/passwd:

     ```
     mgodby@mg-ws1:~$ grep sftponly /etc/passwd
     sftponly:x:1002:1002::/home/sftponly:/bin/false
     ```
   - Manually create the directory `/home/sftponly` as root and assign it ownership and permissions to look like this:

     ```
     mgodby@mg-ws1:/etc$ ls -l /home | grep sftponly
     drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Aug 27 16:07 sftponly
     ```
   - pre-create the interfaces file within `/home/sftponly` and change the permissions to look like this:

     ```
     mgodby@mg-ws1:~$ ls -l /home/sftponly
     total 4
     -rw-rw-r-- 1 sftponly sftponly 95 Aug 27 16:14 interfaces
     ```
2. Now that we have created a user whose sole capability is placing a file called "interfaces" into a specific directory via sftp, we need a cron job that will automatically put your new `interfaces` file into effect.

   - Create a script somewhere (`/root` is pretty safe for this), make it executable, and paste into it the contents found here: [newnet.sh](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8163070/)
   - Create a cron job that runs the script every minute. Here's what the crontab entry would look like if I named my script `newnet.sh` and placed it into the `/root` directory:

     ```
     * * * * * /root/newnet.sh
     ```
   - This will spin up a cron job that automatically checks `/home/sftponly/interfaces` every 1 minute for differences with `/etc/network/interfaces` . If any differences are found, it will copy the new `interfaces` file into place and restart all managed network interfaces.

Let me know if this solution is acceptable to you.

Answer (score 0):

Limit their login to the TTYs using `/etc/security/access.conf`:

```bsh
-:poor_user:ALL EXCEPT tty1 tty2 # Other ttys if needed.
```

Write a custom shell that only opens the editor (and a weak editor at that):

```c
//file: poor_shell.c
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    execl("/usr/bin/nano", "nano", "/etc/network/interfaces", NULL);
}
```

Compile, it make it `setuid` root (or make `/etc/network/interfaces` group writable, and set its group to `poor_user`'s group):

```bsh
gcc -o poor_shell poor_shell.c
chown root:root poor_shell
cp poor_shell /bin
# Either
chmod u+s /bin/poor_shell
# Or:
chown root:poor_user /etc/network/interfaces
chmod g+w /etc/network/interfaces
```

And set this user's shell to `/bin/poor_shell`:

```
chsh poor_user /bin/poor_shell
```